# Leaflet Custom Control position: center

Tags: leaflet

we are hooking up an eye-tracker to control the leaflet map (pan, zoom etc.) We would like to have a custom control that appears at the center of the map (for menu functions) Currently Leaflet does not support position: 'center') (topleft, etc. is supported) ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a custom control on a map on leaflet is performed like this:

For instance a logo:

```js
    var logo= L.control({
        position : 'topleft'
    });
    logo.onAdd = function(map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'myControl');
        var img_log = "<div class="myClass"><img src=\"images/logo.png\"></img></div>";
    
        this._div.innerHTML = img_log;
        return this._div;
    
    }
    logo.addTo(map);
```

Then you can add CSS styling to myClass to center it: (**this part has not been tested by myself)**

```css
    .myClass {
       padding-top:50%;
       padding-left: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: This answer does not work. The control is a child of a div with the class leaflet-top leaflet-left. This div does not have the width of the map...so padding-left 50% just centers the control in its parent div but does not center the control in the map

Answer (score 11):

I get this is an old topic, but anyhow, here is my workaround.

Add some css :

```css
.leaflet-center {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.leaflet-middle {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);

}

.leaflet-center.leaflet-middle {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and patch a the position method.

```js
L.Map.include({
  _initControlPos: function () {
    var corners = this._controlCorners = {},
      l = 'leaflet-',
      container = this._controlContainer =
        L.DomUtil.create('div', l + 'control-container', this._container);

    function createCorner(vSide, hSide) {
      var className = l + vSide + ' ' + l + hSide;

      corners[vSide + hSide] = L.DomUtil.create('div', className, container);
    }

    createCorner('top', 'left');
    createCorner('top', 'right');
    createCorner('bottom', 'left');
    createCorner('bottom', 'right');

    createCorner('top', 'center');
    createCorner('middle', 'center');
    createCorner('middle', 'left');
    createCorner('middle', 'right');
    createCorner('bottom', 'center');
  }
});

Now you have 5 new positions to use.
```

Comment: Looks like a revamp of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621034/5108796

Answer (score 7):

You can simply override the .leaflet-left class to this, and your control will be centered horizontally.

```
.leaflet-left {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

And to center vertically, just override the class .leaflet-top to this:

```
.leaflet-top {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

NOTE: These changes will affect other controls on the map such as zoom controls.

**EDIT:**

If you want to add the functionality to leaflet so that the other controls arent affected, you can do this:

leaflet.js: Beginning at line 4900 I believe?

```
t("top", "left"),
t("top", "right"),
t("bottom", "left"),
t("bottom", "right"),
```

Add these two lines:

```
t("top", "center"),
t("bottom", "center")
```

This would allow for use of positions 'topcenter' and 'bottomcenter'

Then simply add css class for 'leaflet-center':

```
.leaflet-center {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```