# How to locate leaflet zoom control in a desired position

Tags: leaflet

I want to place the zoom control in middle right of the the map i.e. in the middle of the right most side of the map. I have found solution to put the zoom control in different corners using the following code

```
var map = new L.map("map-container",{ zoomControl: false });

   new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topleft' }).addTo(map);
```

So the positions can be

```
topleft
topright
bottomleft
bottomright
```

But my goal is to put the control window in the middle right. Or even I put the control in the corner I want to add some margin to the top. How can I do that? Is there any idea?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

We can create additional Control placeholder(s), besides the 4 provided corners by default.

A nice advantage is that it allows putting several Controls in one of those placeholders. They will stack without overlapping, as in the standard corners.

**JavaScript:**

```js
// Create additional Control placeholders
function addControlPlaceholders(map) {
    var corners = map._controlCorners,
        l = 'leaflet-',
        container = map._controlContainer;

    function createCorner(vSide, hSide) {
        var className = l + vSide + ' ' + l + hSide;

        corners[vSide + hSide] = L.DomUtil.create('div', className, container);
    }

    createCorner('verticalcenter', 'left');
    createCorner('verticalcenter', 'right');
}
addControlPlaceholders(map);

// Change the position of the Zoom Control to a newly created placeholder.
map.zoomControl.setPosition('verticalcenterright');

// You can also put other controls in the same placeholder.
L.control.scale({position: 'verticalcenterright'}).addTo(map);
```

Then it becomes easy styling those placeholders with CSS, because their DOM parent is the map container itself. Hence `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` can be specified with percentages (which use the parent's dimensions).

**CSS:**

```css
.leaflet-verticalcenter {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 50%; /* possible because the placeholder's parent is the map */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* using the CSS3 Transform technique */
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.leaflet-verticalcenter .leaflet-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

As for [vertical centering](https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center) the placeholder itself, you can use your favourite technique. Here I used the CSS3 Transform to offset the placeholder by half of its own height.

If necessary (e.g. for old browsers compatibility), you can rather use a "calculate-on-load" method to perform this offset, similar to [iH8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617036/5108796). But you no longer need to run it on map resize, only when adding new Control(s) to the placeholder.

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/bHJwfm598d1Ps7MpLG0k?p=preview

Note: there is currently an open PR ([Leaflet/Leaflet #5554](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5554)) for this, but since it is not compatible with old versions of Internet Explorer, it will not likely be merged in Leaflet core.

Comment: For Leaflet 1.0.3, I needed to include the line     `z-index: 1000;` in the CSS for leaflet-vertical center.  Otherwise, I could click the control but it wasn't visible. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/437/

Comment: thank you for this solution! it works like a charm on leaflet 1.5.1 too!

Answer (score 64):

Simplest and Accurate

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 6,
    zoomControl: false
});

L.control.zoom({
    position: 'bottomright'
}).addTo(map);
```

[image]

Comment: this adds second zoom controls.

Comment: No, You have to turn off the default zoom control. 
var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 6,
    zoomControl: false
});
this zoomControl: false will disable the default zoom and then
L.control.zoom({
    position: 'bottomright'
}).addTo(map);
This adds the new control at your specified position.

Comment: For some reason the `zoomControl: false` didn't work. Not sure why - possibly a bug? Anyway I added the code `map.zoomControl.remove();` before adding the new zoom control.

Answer (score 16):

This can be done a tad easier, with one line of CSS. Works with responsive design (Bootstrap) and moves additional buttons added with `Leaflet.EasyButton` too.

```
.leaflet-control-container { position: absolute; right: 56px }
```

Comment: This is the best and most concise answer imho. Thank you. :)

Comment: Ah! I need to recall. This technique turned out to be very bad without further adjustments. Because it moves the complete container and the including attribution line from the bottom right out of the viewport. So it's hidden then! Be careful.

Comment: This is doing the job:

    .leaflet-control-container .leaflet-top.leaflet-left {
      position: absolute;
      left: auto;
      right: 10px;
    }

Comment: This moves the whole control container, which include all topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright classes. I think it's pretty good design to solve this using css rather than using noisy js but in that case it prevent further customization of the controler pane. As an example, if the developer wants to put the layer control on the left and zoom control on the right

Answer (score 11):

After you initialized map:

`map.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomright');`

[Here is the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-zoom-option)

> The position of the control (one of the map corners). Possible values are 'topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft' or 'bottomright'

As you see "Options inherited from [Control](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control)"

And here is all methods from Control class:

```
getPosition()
setPosition(<string> position)
getContainer()
addTo(<Map> map)
remove()
```

Comment: this seems the only correct solution to me according to the documentation.
Overriding CSS is very un-intuitive. The other solutions are creating unnecessary boilerplate, e.g. having to unset the default zoom to recreate it on the desired position is not smart imho.
Thanks for sharing

Comment: The documentation has moved.  This would be a better link: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control

Answer (score 8):

**this worked for me**

```
var map = new L.map("map-container",{ zoomControl: false });

L.control.zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58808432/edit) to include an explanation of your code, and justify why it's as good as or better than the other five answers. This question is *four years old* and already has an accepted answer. Answers without explanations on questions like these will tend to get downvoted or deleted.

Answer (score 7):

Grab the map's container height, divide by two. Subtract the zoom's container height, divided by two. Use absolute positioning and assign the top position:

```
var mapHalfHeight = map.getSize().y / 2,
    container = map.zoomControl.getContainer(),
    containerHalfHeight = parseInt(container.offsetHeight / 2),
    containerTop = mapHalfHeight - containerHalfHeight + 'px';

container.style.position = 'absolute';
container.style.top = containerTop;
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yg8phGDcCBS1IlGgpKa2?p=preview

Note that when you're not using a fixed size map container that you'll need to do this every time the map's container get resized. Throw it in a method and hook it up to the map's resize event as in the supplied example.

Answer (score 3):

If your map is not complicated, the easiest way is to use CSS.

In your case, you can just add following CSS:

```
.leaflet-top {
bottom: 0;
}

.leaflet-top .leaflet-control-zoom {
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: To center it perfectly add `margin-top: 0` :
`.leaflet-top .leaflet-control-zoom { top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); margin-top: 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

I needed a new Position for the zoom control like middleleft, So

1- Clone the Leaflet repository

2- In dist/leaflet.css add

```
.leaflet-middle,
.leaflet-top,
.leaflet-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.leaflet-middle{
  top: 50%;
}
.leaflet-middle .leaflet-control {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

3- In src/control/Control.js Add

```
createCorner('bottom', 'right');
createCorner('middle', 'left');
createCorner('middle', 'right');
```

then

```
npm install && npm run build
```

In your script to initiate the map use,

```
L.control.zoom({  position: 'middleleft' }).addTo(map);
```